# Calculate percentage of a False boolean in a column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a boolean column for my data and I need to calculate what percentage is False

Answer (score 0):

```
FalsePercentage = 
VAR totalRows = COUNTROWS('Table')
VAR falseRows = 
  CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    'Table'[BoolColumn] = FALSE()
  )

RETURN DIVIDE(falseRows,totalRows)
```

Set the measure value type as percentage